# Expo - The development server returned response error code 500

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

When I am starting my react-native expo app, I get the following error on my phone:

> The development server returned response error code: 500

Whereas in the metro bundler console I see the following message:

> Unable to resolve "./build/App" from "App.js"

I should note that my code is in `/src` and is written in typescript, and I am running `rimraf /build && npm run tsc --` before running `expo-cli start`. This converts my typescript files to javascript in `/build`.

This constellation has been working for me for the past year with no problem, the only recent change I made was upgrading to expo 32, but this was more that a month ago.

I tried running `npm cache clean --force`, I cleared the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` with no luck.

The package.json file can be found [here](https://github.com/yaron1m/warranty-keeper/blob/master/package.json)

Any ideas?